# How to run vncserver as a user (not root)?

Tags: vnc

I'd like to remote access a desktop of a specfic user and not a root desktop; however when I run the `vncserver` it always produces a rooted desktop.

This could be related to the installation of `tigervnc`. The `.vnc` and `.xauthority` directories are found in `/root` directory.

How can I change this so that I can run `vncserver` at `:1` and produce a specific user desktop?

I also tried using the `vncserver -u username` command but it will not let me access the `.vnc` files.

I think that `tigervnc` has to be removed and installed in the right locations?

Comment: The VNC server will not run as root unless you actually start it as root. It simply runs under whatever user you start it as. So how are you starting it?

Comment: I have to start the vnc server with the root@localhost using the command "vncserver". It will not start using another user account.

Comment: Facing the same issue. @NachodeLeon: any luck?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 4):

Just struggled with this problem for some days and managed to solve it using:

1. Log out and make sure no other user logged-in
2. Log in again as user using TERMINAL, do not use gdm/xdm or graphical manager to login
3. Start `vncserver` in terminal
4. In terminal issue `startx`

What I guess that is happening is that systemd starts the X server and it is run under root user. When somebody login it probably opens a new process and uses `setuid` syscall to set all permissions to the uid that has just logged in. This probably blocks vncserver from getting data from X server for the same user afterwards.

Maybe some kind of systemd configuration or permission changing in filesystem will resolve it as well...

Answer (score 1):

you try https://wiki.ubuntu.com/xdmcp it has Multi-user mode https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC#Multi-user_mode
plan to try this myself in that it may work around the vnc debian grey screen / :( issue better than the mate/lxde installation fix.

have you tried xdmcp remote desktop - it has multi-user mode - it may solve your multi-user issue and other issues encountered with vnc and debian.... per jasonwryan 'essential parts' without links - edit

Answer (score 0):

1.Run the vnc servers as root
2.Copy /root/.vnc/xstartup to /home/user/.vnc ( create .vnc if not already created) 
3.login to user 
4.start vncserver( # vncserver -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -name remote-desktop :1)
5.vncpasswd for setting vnc password
6.try to login through vnc viewer

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Login to target linux user (user that you want to connect with vnc) via ssh (ex: TARGETUSER).

   [root@localhost ~]$ su - TARGETUSER
2. Run following command to change vnc password.

   [TARGETUSER@localhost ~]$ vncpasswd
3. Start vnc server from within target user to create new session for current user.

   [TARGETUSER@localhost ~]$ vncserver
4. Previous command will be created a new session with a number after existing sessions (in this example: 1).

   New 'localhost.localdomain:**1** (TARGETUSER)' desktop is localhost.localdomain:**1**
5. Connect to it via VNC Viewer (ex:SERVER_IP:1) with above created password.

Answer (score 0):

after running (vncserver) in the user terminal and opening a session,

if you connect as root user to serverIp:5901 connect using the normal user to serverIp:5902